# Edge-chromatic numbers of infinite vertex transitive graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite locally-finite and vertex-transitive graph. This means all vertices are of the same finite degree, say $d$. This means that, following Vizing's theorem, all finite subgraphs of $\Gamma$ can be edge-coloured by at most $d+1$ colours. Now using Erdos - de Bruijn theorem we see that actually $\Gamma$ itself can be edge-coloured by at most $d+1$ colours.

My question is the following. Is there an example of a connected infinite locally-finite vertex transitive graph $\Gamma$ such that all vertices in $\Gamma$ have degree $d$ but the edge chromatic number of $\Gamma$ is $d+1$, meaning that $\Gamma$ cannot be edge-coloured by $d$ colours?

Comment: Yeah right. I was supposed to add that $\Gamma$ is connected.